# Pure Nonsense - Nested Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, callback

Consider this nested ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     data: dataString,
     url: "includes/check.php", 
     success:function(result){

          if(result['response']==false){

               $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               dataType: "json",
               data: dataString,
               url: "includes/add.php", 
               success:function(){
                    alert('Success');
               });

          } else {
               alert('A problem has occurred!');
          }

     }
});
```

Both of the php scripts are called successfully and do what they are intended to do but I cannot get the success action of the nested ajax call to display.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the response of the second ajax call? Because you defined `dataType : 'json'` you must respond with valid JSON otherwise the success event will not fire.

Comment: Have you checked for errors? Try adding this to the second ajax: `complete:function(xhr,status) {alert(status);}` Then see what pops up.

Comment: Thanks, if I remove the line 'datatype:json' the alert fires. If I put it back I get nothing. I am emailing the response to myself in the add.php script and the result given is '1' - looks to be valid?

Comment: I added the 'complete' line and I get an error which says: parsererror

Comment: @user2056238: `1` is not a valid JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the `dataType` to `json`, jQuery will only fire the success event if the response is valid JSON and could be parsed. If you send anything that isn't valid JSON, jQuery will not fire the success event. From the comments you said you're outputting `1` which is not valid JSON.

Instead you can output some JSON (in `add.php`):

```
echo json_encode(array('success' => true));
```

Outputs

> {"success":true}

Or remove the json dataType setting and do something like:

```
           success:function(response){
                if(response == "1")
                {
                    alert('Success');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Fail");
                }
           });
```

Side note: use Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools to see ajax responses (instead of emailing it to yourself).

Comment: My php script is as follows...$reply=array('response'=> true).... echo json_encode($reply).... what does parseerror mean? Where is the error in my php or the jscript. So frustrating!

Comment: If that's what the server is outputting then where are you getting `1` from? The parse error means as said in my answer, your PHP did not respond with valid JSON.

Comment: It looks like I had an error in my php script - frustrating though as I can't pin-point what it was exactly which wasn't working and causing the error. How do I use Firebug to read the response? I have just installed it...

Comment: Click on the firebug icon to open it up, then click the net tab. Do your ajax calls and you'll see the HTTP requests being added to the list on the net tab. Click on the request and click the response tab to see the response.

Comment: Awesome that's very useful (Firebug) - saves me having to alert and email output to test. Thank you for all of your help!